# electric-pair-mode: Don't pair if cursor precedes a non-whitespace character

Tags: emacs

After upgrading to Emacs 24.4, I noticed that in some major modes, `electric-pair-mode` correctly "preserves balance" when the cursor precedes a word character, but not in others. Specifically, suppose I have the following code in a buffer, and suppose the pipe character `|` is my cursor:

`foo = ["1", "2", |3"]`

In `python-mode`, typing a double-quote character results in the following:

`foo = ["1", "2", "|3"]`

This is good — `electric-pair-mode` correctly determines that there exists an unmatched double-quote, so there's no need to insert an extra one. However, in `ruby-mode`, I get this instead:

`foo = ["1", "2", "|"3"]`

Is there a way to achieve the same `python-mode` behavior in all other major modes?

**EDIT:**

I just realized that the behavior in `ruby-mode` seems to be dependent on the other contents of the buffer. If I have a buffer with a single line `foo = ["a", "b", "c"]`, then everything seems to be fine. But if my buffer looks like:

```
foo = ["a", "b", "c"]

"#{ bar }"
```

then the extraneous double-quote will show up. Seems like this might be a bug in how `electric-pair-mode` is determining whether it needs to preserve balance.

Does anyone know of a way to force `electric-pair-mode` to *never* insert an extra double-quote if the cursor precedes a non-whitespace character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I just figured it out — `(setq electric-pair-preserve-balance nil)` seems to fix this behavior.

And if anyone's interested, there's an interesting discussion about this on the `emacs-devel` listserv: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2014-04/msg00020.html

Comment: Can you confirm that this was fixed in Emacs 24.5?

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work by default in Emacs 24.5. However, If I use `(setq electric-pair-preserve-balance nil)` then it's fine.

Comment: Yes, but then you lose the balancing preserving goodness. I just tried your first example and it works perfectly. The very last (with the `#` inside a string) example doesn't "work" by design: the last string would be unbalanced if only one `"` were inserted.  Think of it as a way of letting you know there's a sneaky unescaped `#` somewhere. BTW you should file an Emacs bug for this, so we can discuss there.